# Internal Server Error 500 - Azure App Service hosting Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework

My bot on Azure used to work normally some days before without any issue for a year now.

But suddenly, when a user sends a message to the server, the server does not respond and has a Internal Server Error 500, with detailed error information regarding the ManagedPipelineHandler and System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler
[image: Errors]

[image: General Information]
[image: Detailed Error Information]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a temporary issue with the default state service September 15th.  The bug has been fixed. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3466

The default state service is not intended for production bots.  Using the Azure Extensions for state is recommended.  Please review: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/18/saving-state-azure-extensions/

Comment: Eric you are a saver. I appreciate your whole contribution!

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:** The reason this happens is the fact you’ve deployed a binary which doesn’t have an old name (SampleEchoBot.dll). As the web application has now a second binary which tries to host a Messages controller. More details can be found when accessing it via web browser

**Solution:** To  fix it you need to modify your publish profile. Click Publish once again, switch to Settings tab, expand the File Publish Options and check the Remove additional files at destination. After another publish you can deselect this option. The bot should respond now as expected.